# Why aren't Drawn Values always used in List Comprehensions?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, generator

In Haskell, if I want to repeat a value I can write a list comprehension with the following form:

```
repeat_value x n = [x | _ <- [1..n]]
```

Why is it acceptable for me to use a generator that puts its values into a variable, `_`, that's never used?

Comment: Um, why _wouldn't_ it be acceptable?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Logically perhaps, it seems peculiar to assign something to a variable and not use it.

Comment: That's a bit like saying it's peculiar to allow a numerical value `0`.

Comment: @Connor peculiar, maybe, but why shouldn't it be allowed?

Comment: If you *had* to use the variable, you'd be forced to write something less readable, like `[const x y | y <- [1..n]`. Just because you care that the generator provides multiple values doesn't mean you have to care about what those values *are*.

Comment: @chepner Okay, so is the generator there purely to push the list forward?

Comment: A list comprehension evaluates some expression once for each value produced by the generator.  The expression may or may not *need* the value; if it doesn't, you are allowed to use `_` as a "don't-care" binding instead of adding an unused name to the scope. (`_` is not just a conventional variable name. `[_ + 3 | _ <- [1,2,3]]`, for example, does not evaluate to `[4,5,6]`.)

Comment: So yes, the generator is used solely for the fact that you can iterate over it; the contents of the generator don't matter. `[x | <- [6+x..6+x]` would have the same result. You only care that there are `n` distinct values in the generator, not what those values are.

Comment: @chepner Why is it called an "irrefutable pattern", I just tried to use it in the example you gave above and you're right it doesn't evaluate to [4, 5, 6]. Instead, I get an error `Found hole`, what does that mean and is `_` reserved somehow for lazy evaluation?

Comment: It's the use of `_` in `_ + 3` , which is not a pattern, which raises the error. It's basically a *different* use of `_` that isn't really relevant to the question; suffice it to say, no value was bound to a variable named `_`.

Comment: @chepner Does that mean `_` is defined so that it never has values bound to it?

Comment: Yes. In a pattern, it's a distinct part of the syntax, just like `alist@(a:x)`. Outside a pattern, the language treats any identifier starting with a `_` (including `_` itself) as a "hole", an expression with a type but no value, useful for debugging and incremental development. (Don't know what type expression you need in a particular context? Use a hole and find out what the type checker expects.)

Comment: @Connor You could compare with, in other languages, code like `for x in 1..3 do print "hi"` which prints "hi" three times. Here the variable `x` is not used (but could be) in the body of the loop.

Comment: This is natural behaviour. `_` is a wildcard and sometimes you want to process the shape of a list and not its elements. For example in calculating `length xs = sum [ 1 | _ <- xs ]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntactically, `x <- gen` is a repeated pattern-matching operation. For each value provided by the generator, it is matched against the pattern `x`, with whatever binding that might imply. For each pattern-match that succeeds, an expression is evaluated to produce a value to add to the list being built. For example, you could write `[x | Just x <- [Just 1, Nothing, Just 2]]` to get `[1, 2]`.

In your example, you don't need to deconstruct the values with such a complicated pattern; you just need to produce them. You *could* match them against an irrefutable pattern like `y`, but `y` would not be used in the expression on the left, so why bind to a name? You can use the special irrefutable pattern `_` instead.

Comment: So the right hand side of `|` is actually trying to pattern match the left hand side? And then causing bindings to occur where they are applicable?

Comment: Correct. You can see the [required semantics](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11) in the Haskell 2010 report.